# Edit Text button not working

Tags: javascript, function, edit, parent-node

I'm trying to make an edit "button" that, when clicked, will launch a prompt window where you can enter new text that will replace the old text.  The issue, I think, is that there is not an "edit button" in the html, it is created when an item is added to the to-do list.  So I am having trouble targeting the text I want to replace.

Right now the "EditItem" function replaces the Edit button with the text I want, not the To-Do item.  Any advice would really be appreciated!!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> To Do List</title>

        <style>
        body{
            font: sans-serif;
            color: #00b33c;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        p{
            font: sans-serif;
            width: auto;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 500px;
        }
        li {
            border: 2px solid #fff; 
            background: #e5ffff; 
            padding: 10px 10px; 
            color: #000000;
            width: 500px;
        }
        li span{ 
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 200px;


        }
        .checked{
            text-decoration: line-through;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ff0000;

        }

        li span2{
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 12px; 
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;

        }

        li span3{
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

<h1> To Do List</h1>

<p>
    <input type="text" id="inItemText"> 
    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</p>


<ul id="todoList"></ul>

<script src="todolist.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
//CheckBox Feature
function updateStatus() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);

  if (this.checked) {
    itemText.className = "checked";
  } else {
    itemText.className = "";
  }
}

//Delete Button
function deleteItem(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
     inItemText.focus();
     inItemText.select();
    }

//Edit Button
 function editItem(e){
 var newText = prompt("What would you like to change this to?");
    if(newText !== null){
        this.textContent = newText;
         }
     else{
        alert("You must add something");
     }


    }

//Add new item to To-Do List
function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
  totalItems++;

  var listItem = document.createElement("li");

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
  checkbox.onclick = updateStatus;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
  span.textContent = itemText;


  var spanDelete = document.createElement("span2");
  spanDelete.setAttribute("id", listItem.id);
  spanDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
  spanDelete.textContent = "DELETE";
  spanDelete.onclick = deleteItem;


  var spanEdit = document.createElement("span3")
  spanEdit.id = "editId_" + totalItems;
  spanEdit.textContent = "EDIT";
  spanEdit.onclick = editItem;

  listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
  listItem.appendChild(span);
  listItem.appendChild(spanDelete);
  listItem.appendChild(spanEdit);


  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
//Add item to list with ENTER KEY
var totalItems = 0;
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
inItemText.focus();
inItemText.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var itemText = inItemText.value;

        if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
        return false;
    }

      addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), itemText);

  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();
}


//Add item to To-Do List with "Add" Button
var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
  var itemText = inItemText.value;

  if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
  }

  btnNew.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){

        if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
    }

  }
}

  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), itemText);

  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();

}
}
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or code snippet for us :)

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Rassisland/7bkcLfhu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this function in your codes

```
function editItem(e){
 var newText = prompt("What would you like to change this to?");
    if(newText !== null){
        this.textContent = newText;
         }
     else{
        alert("You must add something");
     }

    }
```

change this line `this.textContent = newText;` to

```
this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = newText;
```

here is the snippet

```js
//CheckBox Feature
function updateStatus() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);

  if (this.checked) {
    itemText.className = "checked";
  } else {
    itemText.className = "";
  }
}

//Delete Button
function deleteItem(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
     inItemText.focus();
     inItemText.select();
    }

//Edit Button
 function editItem(e){
 var newText = prompt("What would you like to change this to?");
    if(newText !== null){
        this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = newText;
         }
     else{
        alert("You must add something");
     }

    }

//Add new item to To-Do List
function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
  totalItems++;
 var listItem = document.createElement("li");

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
  checkbox.onclick = updateStatus;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
  span.textContent = itemText;


  var spanDelete = document.createElement("span2");
  spanDelete.setAttribute("id", listItem.id);
  spanDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
  spanDelete.textContent = "DELETE";
  spanDelete.onclick = deleteItem;


  var spanEdit = document.createElement("span3")
  spanEdit.id = "editId_" + totalItems;
  spanEdit.textContent = "EDIT";
  spanEdit.onclick = editItem;

  listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
  listItem.appendChild(span);
  listItem.appendChild(spanDelete);
  listItem.appendChild(spanEdit);


  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
//Add item to list with ENTER KEY
var totalItems = 0;
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
inItemText.focus();
inItemText.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var itemText = inItemText.value;

        if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
        return false;
    }

      addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), itemText);

  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();
}


//Add item to To-Do List with "Add" Button
var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
  var itemText = inItemText.value;

  if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
  }

  btnNew.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){

        if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
    }

  }
}

  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"), itemText);

  inItemText.focus();
  inItemText.select();

}
}
```

```css
        body{
            font: sans-serif;
            color: #00b33c;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        p{
            font: sans-serif;
            width: auto;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 500px;
        }
        li {
            border: 2px solid #fff; 
            background: #e5ffff; 
            padding: 10px 10px; 
            color: #000000;
            width: 500px;
        }
        li span{ 
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 200px;


        }
        .checked{
            text-decoration: line-through;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ff0000;

        }

        li span2{
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 12px; 
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;

        }

        li span3{
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        }
```

```html
    <body>

<h1> To Do List</h1>

<p>
    <input type="text" id="inItemText"> 
    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</p>


<ul id="todoList"></ul>

<script src="todolist.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: HI!  This worked!  Thank you so much for the help, this has been driving me crazy!  I appreciate it!

Comment: you are welcome :D..if this was helpful upvote or star